# My App built with flutter crashes immediately after installation

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

My app crashes Immediately after installation. I didn't get any errors on android studio while making the build. I am new to flutter and I would like to know how to spot and fix the problem. I have provided the code below.

```
C:\src\deliveryboy\flutter_application>flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      52.6s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (22.1MB).
C:\src\deliveryboy\flutter_application>
```

Comment: It works on debug mode ?

Comment: Have you tried to launch the app specific for Android using Android Studio? You could get more logs out there, which may lead to the solution

Comment: `I didn't get any errors on android studio while making the build.` yep, there's a big difference between a compile time error and a runtime error.

Comment: @dm_tr I got this from running debug.  `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. `

Comment: Update your post with the StackTrace

Comment: `The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomeScreen file:///D:/Web%20Design%20Projects%202020/App%20dev/flyweb-12%20%7BAmazCode%7D/flyweb-12/Source%20File%20V_1.2/FlyWeb_Flutter/lib/src/pages/SplashScreen.dart:118:62`

Comment: Looks like a NPE. Does it run correctly on a physical device in debug mode?